# SQL Display Books above average price, display average price of all books.

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

So I have a question regarding sub-queries, I need to display three things: 
Books that are above the average price of books, those books' titles and a column displaying the average price of ALL books in the database. 
I tried the following, and this yielded almost everything I need, however; I still need the average of all books. My issue is with the second snippet of code.

```
SELECT title_name, price 
FROM titles
WHERE price >(SELECT AVG(price) Average_Price FROM titles);
```

Second snippet, where I tried to find the average of all books below.

```
 SELECT AVG(price),title_name, price 
 FROM titles
 WHERE price >(SELECT AVG(price) Average_Price FROM titles);
```

I think I'm missing something pretty simple here, I just can't quite put my finger on it. I want the average for all books so I feel like that needs to be part of the initial statement, but when I add it here it's calculating incorrectly.. I believe this is calculating the average of all the books that are above the average of all books.. If anyone could give me some pointers, I don't even necessarily need the answer given to me.. Just pointed in the right direction perhaps.
Oh it might be helpful to note that we use phpmyAdmin as our work space. Thanks to all who help out. =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
SELECT (select avg(price) from titles) as AvgPrice ,title_name, price 
from titles 
where price > (select avg(price) average_price from titles)
```

The main part of your select is limited by the where clause so your select was getting the average price of all titles that are above the average price.  Having a nested select should get around this (although I work primarily with Oracle, I think this should work with MySQL as well).

Comment: This gave me the correct results. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Put the subquery in the `FROM` clause!

```
SELECT t.title_name, t.price, a.Average_Price 
FROM titles t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(price) as Average_Price FROM titles) a
WHERE t.price > a.Average_Price;
```

This way the subquery is only evaluated *once*, which can be a very important consideration as the database gets larger.